# Mule 4 Cache Scope. How to stop mule cache for based on certain conditions

Tags: caching, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I want to use cache in my mule app. The flow is very simple, I am querying DB on the basis of email, and I want to store the result only if it returns some rows. I referred to this question [Mule Cache Scope How to invalidate mule cache for no payload of DB output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229288/mule-cache-scope-how-to-invalidate-mule-cache-for-no-payload-of-db-output) but this solution is working for mule 3 only as Mule 4 uses [repeatable streams](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/streaming-about).

I tried implementing the following workaround :

1. Wrap the cache scope inside a try scope.
2. Raise an error when I do not want the cache to be stored.
3. On error continue error **for only that error type**

It executes the flow correctly, does not store the result in cache and also gives the successful response but it throws an error (probably in some async process) and I am seeing this in my logs

```
    ERROR 2020-11-20 17:54:36,923 [[MuleRuntime].uber.03: cachingStrategy_null @302bcf75] [processor: testFlow1/processors/1/processors/0/processors/1; event: 594def80-2b2b-11eb-a1d0-a0d37a4d6fab] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
    ********************************************************************************
    Message               : The mapper returned a null value.
    Element               : testFlow1/processors/1/processors/0 @ test:test.xml:131 (Cache)
    Element DSL           : <ee:cache doc:name="Cache" doc:id="8c09cdc7-4fc9-4de1-a961-f74323f6ea7b" cachingStrategy-ref="Caching_Strategy">
                            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger" doc:id="c539273d-7da2-4a20-bbdc-11f9fd4424cc" message="inside cache scope."></logger>
                            <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="be16423b-c018-4949-b441-e81c6abc65ef">
                            <ee:message>
                            <ee:set-payload>%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(payload.store) {
        id: payload.id,
        time: now()
    }
    else {}</ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                            <ee:variables>
                            <ee:set-variable variableName="cacheEntry">%dw 2.0
    output application/java
...
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null value.
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at reactor.core.* (4 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am attaching a snippet of my flow too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Invalidate Key](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/cache-scope-invalidate) operation to remove the key after it was added to the cache.

It should added after the cache scope.